# Назва жінки, що регулярно робить дописи у власному блозі, з використанням фемінитиву?

Tags: словотворення, фемінітиви

Як правильно називати жінку, що робить дописи у власному блозі, з урахуванням фемінітивів: *блогерка* чи *блогиня*?

На мою суб'єктивну думку, варіант *"блогерка"* значно милозвучніший за *"блогиня"*. Але, можливо, існує формальне правило словотворення?

Comment: На мою думку це еволюційний процес. Яке слово переможе, те і вживатиметься надалі частіше за інші. Просто раніше ці змагання різних слів були зарегульовані редакторами видань та ЗМІ, а зараз все простіше - вирішують люди, які вміють писати в соцмережах. Для мого вуха краще звучить "блогиня" або "блогеса". "Блогерка" - якесь воно не таке...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В СУМ-20 є слово "блогер", на мою думку, краще використовувати саме це слово.

[Блогер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191053&page=180) а, ч., інформ. Власник або автор блогу. Блогери об'єднуються у спільноти за інтересами, діляться один з одним своїми міркуваннями, настроями, шукають однодумців (з газ.).